# day and night effect in opengl c++

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, visual-c++, glut

Well, I'm trying to make the day/night cycle in a scene using opengl with c++. I've tried glutTimerFunc.  Although I 've bounded the time slice to be 10000 ms = 10 s, it gave me a very fast flipping effect.

Here is what I have done.

```
void turn (int value){
    if(night)
    {
        glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
        night=!night;
    }
    else
    {
        glDisable(GL_LIGHT1);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
        night=!night;
    }
    //glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(10000,&turn,2);
}
```

And in `DrawGLScene` function I 've called that function. And here is the WinMain function:

```
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE   hInstance,          // Instance
    HINSTANCE   hPrevInstance,      // Previous Instance
    LPSTR       lpCmdLine,          // Command Line Parameters
    int         nCmdShow)           // Window Show State
{
    MSG     msg;                                    // Windows Message Structure
    BOOL    done=FALSE;                             // Bool Variable To Exit Loop

    // Ask The User Which Screen Mode They Prefer
    //if (MessageBox(NULL,"Would You Like To Run In Fullscreen Mode?", "Start FullScreen?",MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION)==IDNO)
    //{
    fullscreen=FALSE;                           // Windowed Mode
    //}

    // Create Our OpenGL Window
    if (!CreateGLWindow("day night",700,500,16,fullscreen))
    {
        return 0;                                   // Quit If Window Was Not Created
    }
    glutTimerFunc(10000,&turn,2);
    //turn(1);
    while(!done)                                    // Loop That Runs While done=FALSE
    {

        if (PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0,PM_REMOVE))   // Is There A Message Waiting?
        {
            if (msg.message==WM_QUIT)               // Have We Received A Quit Message?
            {
                done=TRUE;                          // If So done=TRUE
            }
            else                                    // If Not, Deal With Window Messages
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);             // Translate The Message
                DispatchMessage(&msg);              // Dispatch The Message
            }
        }
        else                                        // If There Are No Messages
        {
            // Draw The Scene.  Watch For ESC Key And Quit Messages From DrawGLScene()
            if (active)                             // Program Active?
            {
                if (keys[VK_ESCAPE])                // Was ESC Pressed?
                {
                    done=TRUE;                      // ESC Signalled A Quit
                }
                else                                // Not Time To Quit, Update Screen
                {
                    DrawGLScene();                  // Draw The Scene
                    SwapBuffers(hDC);               // Swap Buffers (Double Buffering)
                }
            }
            if (keys[VK_F1])                        // Is F1 Being Pressed?
            {
                keys[VK_F1]=FALSE;                  // If So Make Key FALSE
                KillGLWindow();                     // Kill Our Current Window
                fullscreen=!fullscreen;             // Toggle Fullscreen / Windowed Mode
                // Recreate Our OpenGL Window
                if (!CreateGLWindow("day night",700,500,16,fullscreen))
                {
                    return 0;                       // Quit If Window Was Not Created
                }

            }
        }
    }

    // Shutdown
    KillGLWindow();                                 // Kill The Window
    return (msg.wParam);                            // Exit The Program
}
```

Comment: What is this surreal combination of GLUT and Win32?  Pick an event loop.  *One* event loop.

Comment: @genpfault yeah, that's more or less what my answer said, once the OP had clarified that he wasn't using `glutMainLoop`.

Answer (score 3):

If your `DrawGLScene` has been registered using `glutDisplayFunc` and is therefore called to draw each frame then you'll also be (re)registering your timer function *every* time you redraw the frame, i.e. every time you call `glutPostRedisplay()`.

To start the timer sequence you should just call `glutTimerFunc` once, *before* you call `glutMainLoop`, and not call it in `DrawGLScene`.

It's still necessary to call `glutTimerFunc` *within* the timer function to initiate the next flip.

---

**EDIT**   I see you're not even using `glutMainLoop`.  This means that your call to `glutTimerFunc` isn't doing anything.  GLUT based handlers *only* work when they're dispatched by the `glutMainLoop` function.

The only reason your code is doing anything at all is because you're calling `DrawGLScene` within a *Windows* event loop which then directly calls your timer function in each pass through the Windows event loop.  This is the source of the unexpectedly high frequency.

If you intend to stick with using the Windows event model then you'd be better off just using standard Windows timer events (i.e. `SetTimer`) to handle the flips.

Alternatively rewrite your code to use `glutMainLoop` and have all of the keypresses and other events handled by GLUT.

Comment: I've tried that, but I got a constant light. I mean there is no changing at all.

Comment: @user1412823 did you see the update about there still being a need to call `glutTimerFunc` _inside_ the timer func?

Comment: yes, I did. note: I have WinMain function and a while loop, I guess it is the same as mainloop, isn't it?.

Comment: @user1412823 I don't think so, but I never used GLUT on Windows.  Show us what's in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is because real day/night is not a boolean, it is a gradual change between day and night. In addition, only 10 seconds is a very short day/night cycle- you usually want a few minutes at least.

Comment: I used 10s for test purposes only.the result was a cycle -night and day-in less than a second.

Comment: The `glutTimerFunc` only has 100 as an argument.